# Why is the Atomic Blimp not showing up?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

When you download the Atomic Blimp DLC, a blimp icon appears at the Vinewood Racetrack and a new contact is added to your phone, "Blimp". I know I can get to the Blimp by simply accessing the racetrack.

The problem is whenever I try calling the "Blimp" contact, a woman answers and says ***exactly this***:

> "I'll send one out to you right away".

No matter how long I wait, the blimp never shows up! I have tried this dozens of times in multiple areas and the blimp icon never moves.

Out of rage, I then take my anger out on nearby citizens:

[image]

Anyway, What am I doing wrong?

---

***EDIT:***

The problems addressed in this question have been fixed with the recent patch.

Comment: Try calling the blimp outside of the area where it should spawn, and then go to the blimp spot.

Comment: Poor mime. R.I.P.

Comment: @YoungGuilo in my defense, the mime was coming at me with an invisible ladder, as you can clearly see. So self defense.

Comment: Gotta watch out for those invisible knives. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go the the [wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/Atomic_Blimp) and it explains everything.

> Can be ordered on a special in-game app after completing Franklin's intro mission. Has to be picked up at the location give on the map. One of the most common locations for pick up is at Los Santos International Airport.

So you have to go to that location. The woman just says she'll have it ready for you on the pad. Not come to you.

Comment: another common location is the Racecourse.

Answer (score 15):

You're misunderstanding something.

When you call the Blimp contact, the woman says:

> Of course, sir. I'll get one sent out to *the nearest available drop-off point.*

The thing is, unlike a cab, that can go almost anywhere, a zeppelin is huge and can't simply land whereever.

Calling the Blimp makes its icon appear on your map. You have to go there yourself.

Comment: This doesn't add to anything that has already been said.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I blame my slow internet connection and my high ping.

Comment: @YoungGuilo It does, actually. The additional "what she actually said" makes this a more informative answer, because it explains the underlying misunderstanding as well.

Comment: In my game, the woman said exactly "I'll send one out to you right away". There are several possible responses.

Comment: @Dom That's an interesting wrinkle. That would further explain things!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie not to mention, the blimp icon is ALWAYS on my map, regardless of calling the blimp contact.

Comment: Yeah but, an icon DIDN'T show up for me ;-;

Answer (score -3):

It will be at the airport in Los Santos.